# Is Spring Kafka KafkaListener annotation able to take config property as topic name?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, apache-kafka, spring-kafka

I have the following definition:

```
    @KafkaListener(
            topics = "${app.kafka.eventTopic}",
            groupId = "${app.kafka.consumerGroupId}",
            concurrency = "${app.kafka.concurrency}"
    )
```

And I defined these config properties in my yaml file like:

```
app:
  kafka:
    eventTopic: topicName
    consumerGroupId: groupName
    concurrency: 10
```

I am new to SpringBoot and I saw some SO posts that claim syntax like ${app.kafka.eventTopic} does not work as is for @Value() annotation and needs ConfigurationProperties class to "translate" the properties values to Java variables. If that's true for @Value annotation, does it work the same way here for KafkaListener annotation content?

Comment: Test it and you know. Replacing placeholders in annotation attributes needs to be added to the annotation processors of the annotation. An annotation is nothing more than metadata. So it needs to be in the processor, if it isn't in the processor it isn't supported.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work in a normal spring boot application without any "translators". E.g. this should work fine as long as the corresponding property is in your `application.properties` or `application.yaml`:

```
@KafkaListener(
    topics = "${kafka.topics.consume.somedata}", 
    id = MyConsumer.CONTAINER_ID)
```

You can even use more advanced SPeL expressions, e.g.:

```
@KafkaListener(topics = "#{'${consumer.topics}'.split(',')}", ...)
```

You can read more about SpEL [here](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-expression-language).

Under the hood indeed the Value and KafkaListener annotations are handled slightly differently. One by the [AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/beans/factory/annotation/AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.html) and the other by [KafkaListenerAnnotationBeanPostProcessor](https://docs.spring.io/spring-kafka/api/org/springframework/kafka/annotation/KafkaListenerAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.html).

Comment: See also respective documentation: https://docs.spring.io/spring-kafka/docs/current/reference/html/#kafka-listener-annotation. This has nothing to do with Spring Boot. That's why Spring Boot doesn't have  any docs on the matter.

Comment: does the config property have to be under `kafka.topics`? Or I can put it in any property like `app.kafka.topic`?

Comment: @return0 you can use any property like `app.kafka.topic`

Comment: Thank you all guys. It's an awesome community!